# batch usb letter execute command

Tags: scripting, batch

I have and batch script to execute a command to delete several ext.
Example:

```
set /p drive=Choose the letter of usb:
if %drive%== E goto E
```

Example (if you choose E)

```
E:
del /f /q E:\*.lnk *.inf *.init
```

But only delete the first one (*.lnk). The rest to redirect to the drive c (where i execute batch)
Example:

```
Can't find C:\*.inf
```

I don't want to do this:

```
del /f /q E:\*.lnk
del /f /q E:\*.inf
del /f /q E:\*.init
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fairly quickly solve it by prefixing the other extensions like you did the first:

```
del /f /q E:\*.lnk E:\*.inf E:\*.init
```

Really though, instead of creating a block for each drive manually you could use your variable here to do the work for you:

```
set /p drive=Choose the letter of usb:

del /f /q %drive%:\*.lnk %drive%:\*.inf %drive%:\*.init
```

Comment: I have a aditional question:  if exist %drive%:\data cd %drive%:\data (How to remove those within folders. Example del /f /q *.lnk *.inf inside data). Thanks

Comment: You can use `Del /F/Q/S/A <path>\*.ext` to delete all items matching `*.ext` in all sub folders starting at `<path>`

Answer (score 0):

Taz, I will borrow your answer to show the full example.

```
:TOP
set /p drive=Choose the letter of usb:
If "%drive%" EQU "" Goto :TOP
Set drive=%drive:~0,1%
del /f/q/s/a %drive%:\*.lnk %drive%:\*.inf %drive%:\*.init
```

Only accepts the first character typed and checks for no imput.

The `/s` will perform the check for the file in all sub folders starting from the path given.
The `/a` will delete all file, even if they are hidden. Not 100% sure about read-only files though...

Quotes `"` are not used around parameters because the only user provided data is a single letter and there is no whitespace within the prewritten parameters.